# How can I implement a Hierarchical concurrent finite state machine in C (HCFSM)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, fsm

I am using a FSM to model the behaviour of an embedded system I am developing. After some initial tests I have a FSM coded in C working quite well. The approach I used to code the FSM was the pointer-to-function table where I define a table with all the functions that takes place in each state.

```
void(*state_table[])(void) = {
conection,
Idle,
cal,
bi,
pot,
gal,
eis,
PrepE,
Pret,
Meas,
FS_ch,
Ending,
Error };
```

Now the next step is to modeling some complexities of the requirements that I could not solve with the first approach. In this new model I would like to use some concurrency to model two FSMs that should work at the "same time", and I also used some hierarchy to put those FSMs inside a superstate.

The problem I have now is that I am not sure how to code this concurrency and hierarchy using C. I was taking a look to the QP framework but I think my FSM is not still so complex to begin to use those kind of frameworks.

This is the FSM I designed.
[image]
The states 71 and 72 are the concurrent states inside the superstate 7. The execution is acutally independent between them, they doesn't share any variable.

How could I  implement this concurrency and hierarchy using C?

Comment: you can watch the concept of propagators to implement concurrency.  https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/propagators/

Comment: Are you using any RTOS?

Comment: Why don't you code them too as arrays of function pointers?

Comment: Yes, two more tables of the same struct.  Being state machines, they will run concurrently. if you call states of both tables from their superstate handler.  The idea behind state machines is to mimic concurrency in a single threaded system.

Comment: @GauravPathak No, I want to keep it as simple as possible if I can. So RTOS is not an option for me now.

Comment: Without a single "?" is the "question" it is hard to tell what it is you are asking.  You seem to be just canvassing opinion which makes this either  too broad or unclear.

Comment: @Clifford Question edited. Basically my question is about how to take this idea of concurrency and hierarchy used in the 7 state to C language.

Comment: @osuarez : There are those that will still object to and vote-down a question phrased as "What is the best way to...?" since that is definitively a matter of opinion.  Better to ask "How can I ...?"  you will get the same variety of answers, but they need make no claim to being the "best" way.  It is also a good idea to make the title a question - it attracts the right kind of viewers - i.e. those likely to be able to answer.

Comment: @Clifford : I edited the question again for clarity.

Comment: @Lundin I will try this way using the Clifford's example below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The outer state-machine runs in a continuous loop, while sub-states and sub-state-machines must run to completion. Concurrency in the absence of a preemptive scheduler must be implemented cooperatively - the "concurrent" states must be executed sequentially, but each should perform a deterministic guaranteed-to-complete operation on each invocation - i.e. no indefinite busy-waits or delays or processing that take longer that your real-time constraints allow (this is fundamental to state-machine constraint in any case).

The substate-machines can be implemented identically to the main state machine but without the "big-loop".  For example:

```
// Main state machine
static int current_state0 = 0 ;
int main( void )
{
    static const void(*state_table[])(void) = 
    {
        conection,
        Idle,
        cal,
        bi,
        pot,
        gal,
        eis,
        PrepE,
        Pret,
        Meas,
        FS_ch,
        Ending,
        Error 
    } ;

    // Main loop - execute the current state
    for(;;)
    {
        state_table[current_state0]() ;
    }
}

void superState7()
{
    // Execute concurrent sub-statemachines
    subStateMachine71() ;
    subStateMachine72() ;
}


// Sub-state machine
static int current_state71 = 0 ;
void subStateMachine71()
{
    static const void(*state_table[])(void) = 
    {
        state711,
        state712,
        state713,
        state714
    } ;

    // Execute current substate
    state_table[current_state71]() ;
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks Clifford. I was making a FSM skeleton using your idea and makes sense. I will test it in the next days.